# SQL How to return column value based in other substring position delimited by commas

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, substring, charindex

My first post! I hope that you help me :)

I'm working in SQL 2017 and I have a table like this:

`+----+------------------+------------------+
| ID  |       Col1       |       Col2       |
+-----+------------------+------------------+
| 110 | 450,2,50,110,600 | 3,45,30,901,1001 |
| 250 | 2,250,300,1      | 1,33,540,900     |
| 45  | 1,45,320         | 200,444,600      |
+-----+------------------+------------------+`

The logic is to find the ID position in Col1 and return based in that position the substring in Col2.

Example:

ID 110 match 4th position in Col1 so should return 901 value in Col2.
ID 250 match 2nd position in Col1 so should return 33 value in Col2.
ID 45  match 2nd position in Col1 so should return 400 value in Col2.

I made different attempts without any success, probably I'm in wrong direction.

Can you please help with this?

The output that I want is the specific values from Col2.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include in your question what you want the final output to look like?

Comment: Don't store CSV in your SQL tables like this.  Even if you get an answer, it will be bufugly and hard to use/maintain.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I agree with @TimBiegeleisen. The ONLY answer that makes any sense here is to fix your data model. What you have violates 1NF and is horrible to work with.

Comment: Bear in mind that lots of people do not own the db, they do not design the db, but still have to work under certain conditions handed to them. So comments stating that this is bad design are true, but not at all helpfull here...

Comment: Hi! I didn't build this table or my source is a CSV file. The sql source table that I have to work with is already with this struture.

Comment: @SQL_M on the contrary. Many times people around here are able to fix their design, they didn't know it was bad in the first place.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? You have an answer that works if you are on 2016+. If you are on an older version it can still be done, just a slightly different approach.

Comment: Hi @SeanLange, I'm using SQL 2017 but I'm getting the message Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT' when I run the first answer.

Comment: Are you sure you are are using 2017? Not your version of SSMS but the version of the server you are connecting to.

Comment: @SeanLange when I run select @@version I get Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64) 
 Aug 22 2017 17:04:49 
 Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Evaluation Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64>

Comment: Maybe you have compatibility set to an older version? See the answer below from Cool_Br33ze. It should work for you.

Comment: I just change the compatibility set and It worked @SeanLange. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQL Server 2016+ (I'm not going to do one for earlier because of STRING_SPLIT support

```
DECLARE @BadDesign table (ID int, Col1 varchar(200), Col2 varchar(200));

INSERT @BadDesign VALUES
    (110,'450,2,50,110,600', '3,45,30,901,1001'),
    (250,'2,250,300,1', '1,33,540,900'),
    (45 ,'1,45,320', '200,444,600')    

SELECT
    * 
FROM
    @BadDesign B
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), value 
     FROM  
        STRING_SPLIT(B.Col1, ',')
    ) b1
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), value
     FROM
        STRING_SPLIT(B.Col2, ',')
     ) b2
WHERE
    B.ID = b1.value AND b1.rn = b2.rn
```

No guarantees on ROW_NUMBER consistency over the output of STRING_SPLIT.

Edit: also requires [database compatibility to be 130](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) or above (SQL Server 2016)

> The STRING_SPLIT function is available only under compatibility level
>   130. If your database compatibility level is lower than 130, SQL Server will not be able to find and execute STRING_SPLIT function. You
>   can change a compatibility level of database using the following
>   command: ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130

Comment: Hi @gbn. Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm getting Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT' message when I run your script. I'm using SQL 2017.

Comment: Check database compatibilitiy level as per the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql

Answer (score 4):

Using a Custom String Split Function (this answer is using one written by Aaron Bertrand), so not restricting the use on SQL2016+

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStringsOrdered (
      @List         NVARCHAR(2000)
    , @Delimiter    NVARCHAR(32)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
        SELECT
            rn  = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number)
            , Item
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    Number
                    , Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(
                                                    @List
                                                    , Number
                                                    , CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                FROM
                    (
                        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
                        FROM
                            sys.all_objects
                    ) AS n(Number)
                WHERE
                    Number                                                  <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
                AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter))  = @Delimiter
            ) AS y
    );
GO
```

And amending the query created by @gbn in his/her answer - is this allowed on SO?

```
DECLARE @BadDesign table (ID int, Col1 varchar(200), Col2 varchar(200));

INSERT @BadDesign VALUES
    (110,'450,2,50,110,600', '3,45,30,901,1001'),
    (250,'2,250,300,1', '1,33,540,900'),
    (45 ,'1,45,320', '200,444,600')    

SELECT
    B.*, Col1Value=b1.Item, Cal2Value = B2.Item
FROM
    @BadDesign B
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), F.Item
     FROM  
        dbo.SplitStringsOrdered(B.Col1, ',') F
    ) b1
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)), F1.Item
     FROM
        dbo.SplitStringsOrdered(B.Col2, ',') F1
     ) b2
WHERE
    b1.rn = b2.rn
```

Comment: Yes, it's allowed and a +1 from me for earlier versions

Comment: i appreciate the +1 @gbn

Comment: Hi @Cool_Br33ze! Thanks for your answer! It worked!! your script return just what I need :) +1 for you. Top!!

Comment: @DinisFonseca I'm happy to help